# remove background from all states in mat-input , angular material16, angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular16 with material16. I need to remove background fill from mat-input/textarea, completely, for all states.

I am able to do this for simple input state, but that css is not working on hover/focus.

Please help.

Comment: I assume, you tried already the pseudo-selectors `:hover` and `:focus`. If so, then simply inspect the css rules, because something else overwrites this. If not, then you know, what to do.